# Multi-Dimensional Arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, logic

I have an array structure like this, which I'm able to print out just fine:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [title] => blah
      [author] => Bob
      [link] => randomlink
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
      [title] => random
      [author] => George
      [link] => randomlink
    )

  [2] => Array
    (
      [title] => blah
      [author] => Bob
      [link] => randomlink
    )
)
```

Basically, I want to be able to print out only the information in the array that's related to the 'author' 'Bob'.  As you can see, he has two items in there.  When I print out the array, it should only show the 0 and 2 array since those are the only ones that contain the 'author' which is 'Bob'.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as $a) 
{
 if($a['author'] === 'Bob') {
   echo $a['title'];
   echo $a['author'];
   echo $a['link'];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($arr as $item)
{
   if($item['author'] != 'Bob')
   {
      continue;
   }
   // print out Bob's stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code:

```
foreach($array as $subarray)
{
   if(strcasecmp($subarray['author'],'Bob') === 0)
      print_r($subarray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `foreach`

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
  if ($item['author']) {
    // Do something with $item
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok ! try this :

```
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
if($array[$i]['author'] == 'bob'){
    echo $array[$i]['title']." > ".$array[$i]['author']." > ".$array[$i]['link']."\r\n<br>";
   }
      }
```

...

Comment: Sidenote: Don't use functions in the `for`-test-expression.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa as he asked he wants to print only with the author "bob" so if it doest exists or doest match it will not echo it ...

Comment: @KingCrunch which function you talking about ! count() is reserved function it think also i can declare the value with any other var earlier so there isnt any problem ? r u talking about count() ?

Comment: @Soumo: The test expression gets executed in every iteration, so I suggest to define the number of values before. You can use the "pre"-expression for that http://ideone.com/kTfVX At all, it wasn't a real problem, just a sidenote ;)

Comment: @SoumoGorai This is not the point of the question. If the key of the array will be 1, 2 and 4, using your loop you'll try to search in the index 1, 2 and 3. So it's wrong.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa hmmm ! ok but as you can see the question owner accepted a answer which is same as mine except i use for loop and he used foreach ! you are right but seems like its ok now .